# ament_cpplint: Relative paths like . and .. are not allowed

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of my ROS2 Rolling CIs started failing today against the ament_cpplint test. I have `my_package` with two files in the `src/` directory: my_class.cpp and my_class.hpp. The line caught by ament_cpplint is the line `#include "./my_class.hpp` in my_class.cpp.

The error is:

```
my_package/src/my_class.cpp should include its header file my_package/src/my_class.hpp. Relative paths like . and .. are not allowed.  [build/include] [5]
```

From memory, the reason I had the leading `./` was that it supressed a stange issue in ament_cpplint about including relative directories. However, I see in a recent [PR for rclcpp](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/1859/files), they remove the leading `./` from the includes. Has this issue been resolved such that we can use just use `#include "my_class.hpp"`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395304/ament_cpplint:-relative-paths-like-.-and-..-are-not-allowed./) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2022-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question,

Changing `#include "./my_class.hpp"` to `#include "my_class.hpp"` simply solves the problem.

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0